# Blocking JavaScript event propagation

Tags: javascript, event-handling, opencart

I am creating an opencart e-shop and there is a bug, where when I am typing to a textarea element, another part of the UI is modified.
I want to stop this, so I thought to do that with JavaScript. I am trying to overwrite the change and input events like:

```
function stopEvent(ev) { 
    ev.preventDefault();
    ev.cancelBubble=true;
    ev.stopPropagation();
}

element.addEventListener("change", stopEvent, false);
```

but does not work. Is it possible that the CMS does that in a different way other than tapping these "typing" events? Is something wrong with the script? I had found the events attached to the element with
`getEventListeners(element)`.

Comment: Typing triggers key (press/up/down) events, not change events. But really you shouldn't try to fix the textarea, you need to fix the other part of the UI which listens to events even when it doesn't have focus. Can you share a complete [mcve] with the problem, please?

Comment: You were right, I eventually shouldn't have fixed the textarea, since the event was affecting many parts of the UI. Also, the keypress events were the triggers. I ended up in a different solution, modifying the template code, writen in Vue.js.